# How to use the 'return' statement properly in Python

Tags: python-3.x, return, syntax-error

there are some significant errors in my code and I don't understand what is causing them. I have tried changing the format of my return statement, but I keep receiving the same error.

This is my current code:

```
print("Kiran's Quiz: A quiz made by Kiran!\n")

def answers():
    points = 0
    x = input("Question 1: How far away is  the Earth from the Sun? Give your answer in 'n million miles'.")
    y = input("Question 2: What colour is white? Give your answer in 'x colour(s)'.")
    z = input("Question 3: What temperature is boiling water? Give your answer in 'n degrees centigrade'.")

    while (x != "93 million miles") or (y != "every colour") or (z != "100 degrees centigrade"):
        print ("You got it wrong. -1 point for you!.")
        points -= 1
        print("You have" + str(points) + ("points.")
    
    points += 1
    print("Hooray, you got it correct! +1 to you!")

    return x, y, z

answers()
```

and I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 17
    return x, y, z
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[Code and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfR0x.png)

Comment: In your `while` loop, your second `print` is missing a close parenthesis `)`.

Comment: `return` is not properly indented

Comment: Also, `(points) - 1` does nothing. You must `points -= 1`

Comment: `return` should be in `def answer()`. You are writing outside.

Comment: everyone in the comments above me is correct.

Comment: Thanks guys, every one of your comments helped!

Comment: Hi, this post was a long time ago (and I was a beginner then - all of you helped me get better at programming helping me fix these mistakes) and downvotes are negatively affecting my reputation. What can I do to rectify this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Errors:**

- `print` statement missing a close parenthesis
- `return` outside of function

**Code:**

```
print("Kiran's Quiz: A quiz made by Kiran!\n")

def answers():
    points = 0
    x = input("Question 1: How far away is  the Earth from the Sun? Give your answer in 'n million miles'.")
    y = input("Question 2: What colour is white? Give your answer in 'x colour(s)'.")
    z = input("Question 3: What temperature is boiling water? Give your answer in 'n degrees centigrade'.")

    while (x != "93 million miles") or (y != "every colour") or (z != "100 degrees centigrade"):
        print ("You got it wrong. -1 point for you!.")
        points -= 1
        print("You have" + str(points) + ("points."))

    points += 1
    print("Hooray, you got it correct! +1 to you!")
    return (x, y, z)

answers()
```